# GSEC or GCIH, for a Security Analyst?

Tags: certification, career

I've been with this confusion of getting a certification for a long time!! With the aim of becoming a Security Analyst/Tester, and for a good kick start, which one of these two is good?
**GSEC or GHIC??**
I took a look at the objectives of both these certs.
GSEC objects to end to end concept with a basic toolset/practical problems (IMHO)
GHIC objects to real problems/practical solutions.. (at least that's what i think).

P.S. I have some basic(Theoretical) understanding of security concepts

**(Update)** edit: omg!! i just took a look at their training program which costs $4000 !! real? also, i took a look at few gsec books at amazon and they were outdated.. so, is there a way to get a proper course-ware outside of sans and expect it to cover the syllabus?

Comment: What about CREST? http://www.crest-approved.org/

Comment: hmm.. i went for isc2 and sans since i see these two more often..

Comment: @Cheekysoft - CREST is a certification to show you are at the top standard of penetration testing. It certainly won't be a starting point :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISC2 CISSP will not give you what you need to be a tester, although it does give you access to a range of useful information for a security practitioner.

You can get a lot of practical experience and learning through free online resources such as [OWASP's WebGoat](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebGoat_Project) - and by playing around with tools such as the [Backtrack](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/) suite, so I would recommend them first before spending too much money.

Have a look at these questions:

- [Comparing online security courses](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/comparing-online-security-courses-elearnsecurity-vs-offensive-security)
- [Good security certification](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3722/a-good-security-certification)
- [CEH or GIAC - which should I pursue](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3752/ceh-or-giac-which-one-should-i-pursue)
- [SANS training - worth it?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5569/sans-training-worth-it)

Or in fact any of the **Related Questions** on the right.

As @Cheekysoft mentioned, [CREST](http://www.crest-approved.org/) is the UK's gold standard on penetration testing, and it is also being rolled out in other countries.

You should also look at the [Penetration Testing Execution Standard](http://www.pentest-standard.org/index.php/Main_Page), which is being developed as a methodology/toolset for how to manage penetration tests.

Answer (score 3):

I would say do both to be honest.

GSEC will give you the foundations that you need to know (similar to the information you would get from doing a CISSP) but it won't give you the knowledge you want to be a Security Analyst or Tester.

GCIH is all about incident handling and basic hacker techniques, and as your career progresses you'll learn that they are *basic*.

To be a good security analyst you need experience, but having those certs will get you on your way. I would also look at the OSCP offering by Offensive Security and the GPEN cert by SANS/GIAC.

Answer (score 0):

Do whichever your job requires/boss will give you a raise for ;)  Ultimately they don't matter, the knowledge required to do your job does.